# Using LINQ .OrderByDescending not working

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to build a query where there is one student name then a nested collection of clubs he belongs to. I want to organize this collection with OrderByDescending. I am stuck with what to provide to the parenthesis.

```
public void GetStudentsClubNameRev()
        {
            try
            {
                using (SchoolContainer = new SchoolContainer())
                {

                    var query = from student in SchoolContainer.Students
                                select new
                                {
                                    StudentName = student.Name,
                                    ClubName = student.StudentClubMatches
                                        .Where(s =>s.StudentId == student.Id)
                                        .Select(c => c.Club.Name)
                                        .OrderByDescending(o => "Name")
                                };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

In .OrderByDescending(o => "Name") I don't know what my predicate is. I want to say orderbydescending on the Name which is club name. But I get errors because I don't think I understand what it wants.

[image: Screenshot of edmx]

Comment: Why do you have that try/catch block there? If there are problems in your code, don't you want to know about them and fix them? Get rid of the try/catch!

Comment: @JohnSaunders There is a try/catch block there because when I make a trip to the database it is possible that the connection fails. I've not written anything inside the brackets because it's a programming test and they are not asking for it.

Comment: If it were _my_ programming test, then you would have failed it. You don't know how to _handle_ the exception, so you should not catch it. Allow it to propagate up to some piece of code which _does_ know how to handle it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders But if I am asked to code a specific functionality and I code something else, it is demonstrating that I can't follow instructions.

Comment: No, it shows that you have a brain. If you also have a mouth, then you will be able to explain what your brain did, and why. Be a human, not a sheep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you OrderByDescending before Select you could also do this:

```
var query = from student in SchoolContainer.Students
    select new
    {
        StudentName = student.Name,
        ClubName = student.StudentClubMatches
            .Where(s =>s.StudentId == student.Id)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.Club.Name)
            .Select(c => c.Club.Name)
    };
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked. Can I ask why that order? Where then orderby then select.

Comment: Because once you have called Select(c => c.Club.Name), you have "projected" the query into a new shape, which only contains the Club.name, a string, and as such it doesn't contain any other properties of the original list. By ordering first, you ensure that you still have access to the whole object, not only the Name.

Comment: Oh ok that makes perfect sense. I will remember that in the future :)

Comment: MSDN says "Projects each element of a sequence into a new form"  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

After you've selected "Club.Name", the current enumerable is just a string.  You just want a pass-through selector:

```
.Select(c => c.Club.Name)
.OrderByDescending(name => name)
```

Comment: My code compiles with what you suggested but when I try to look at the values I get this error: Results View = The type '<>f__AnonymousType1<StudentName,ClubName>' exists in both 'ITNTest.exe' and 'EntityFramework.dll'

Answer (score 0):

To sort by a property you should use the following:
**Code:**

```
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Name)
```